# Showing $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{2^n+d}{2^n}) = e^d$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, substitution

Basically the title.

The solution in the book I am reading says to look at the function $f(x) = \ln(1+dx)$. Clearly, $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+dx)}{x} = d$. I follow so far. But then, the author says "Applying the continuous function $e^x$" yields $\lim_{x \to 0} (1+dx)^{\frac{1}{x}} = e^d$.

I got completely lost here. I have no idea how the author applied $e^x$ on the LHS to get the new limit. I understand once I have this new limit what I have to do to prove the rest, but I am not sure how the application works. I may just not be remembering some log rules, but some guidance would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: They did $e^{\frac{\ln(1+dx)}{x}}=e^{ln[(1+dx)^{1/x}]}=(1+dx)^{1/x}$.

Comment: Btw $dx$ is very unfortunate notation, as it almost always denotes the differential with respect to $x$.

Comment: Notice that the step explained in the comment above is only possible because $x \mapsto e^x$ is continuous. Therefore $$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to a} x_n\right) = \lim_{n\to a} \exp(x_n)$$ for any $a\in[-\infty,\infty]$ and any sequence $(x_n)_n$.

Comment: You should keep in mind that the *definition* of $\alpha^\beta$ (for $\alpha >0$) is $$\alpha^\beta\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \mathrm e^{\beta\ln(\alpha)}.$$

Comment: The title has a limit of 1?

Answer (score 1):

As the exponential function is continuous, the author uses 
$$ \lim_{x\to0}g(x)=a\implies \lim_{x\to0}e^{g(x)}=e^d.$$
Here, $g(x)=\frac{\ln(1+dx)}x$, so
$$e^{g(x)}=e^{\frac{\ln(1+dx)}x}=\left(e^{\ln(1+dx)}\right)^{1/x} =(1+dx)^{1/x}$$